# Strange charset issue

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have a weird issue with what appears to be character encoding.  Some accented characters, i.e. `ê`,`ç`,`ã`, prior to the first about 4k of an .asp page are displayed as `ï¿½`, no matter which charset I specify.

If I pad the page prior to the display of the characters, they display fine.  We are using IIS 7.5, I've tried setting the charset in the page itself using meta tags, and in the IIS headers, but nothing seems to affect the characters at the start of the page.

Changing the charset to UTF-8 makes all of them look bad (`�`) however.

Comment: What is the encoding of the physical ASP file *(check using NotePad++ or something similar)*?

Comment: `ï¿½` is `UTF-8` BOM… if displayed under Code Page 1252

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @rcdmk no, not other than a bad hack of outputting some repeated characters in an HTML comment to pad the page out to the length required to make things behave

Answer (score 0):

Some things to solve this may include:

- Open the file in Notepad++, UTFCast or something similar and save the page to a defined encoding (UTF-8 for example)
- Look for each encoding or charset reference in the file and change it to the same encoding as above
- Set the Content-Type header and META tags to the same encoding
- Set the Response.Charset property to the desired charset
- Set database collation and charset to the same encoding
- Make sure any included files are in the same encoding